# Multiply by one gives x not defined at a point?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, continuity

If we take f(x)=3 and multiply top and bottom by x-1 we get 3x-3/x-1. So now x is not defined at x=1 why is this if we have only multiplied by 1?

Comment: Because if $x=1$ you haven't multiplied by $1$, you've multiplied by $\displaystyle \frac{0}{0}$ which is an indeterminate.

Comment: That makes sense thanks